# Preview customer tax rate

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I use metered usage prices in a monthly subscription, and tax rates are automatically calculated by Stripe Tax. Prices are set to be exclusive of tax, but I need to display the price including tax to the customer before the subscription is created. How do I fetch the tax rate for a customer/price combination?

The only thing I found is the [Upcoming Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming?lang=go) API. But the problem is that this does not appear to work with metered billing:

```golang
items := []*stripe.SubscriptionItemsParams{{ Price: "price_id", Quantity: stripe.Int64(1) }
invoice.Upcoming(&stripe.InvoiceUpcomingParams{
    Customer: &cus.ID,
    SubscriptionItems: items,
    AutomaticTax: &stripe.InvoiceAutomaticTaxParams{
        Enabled: stripe.Bool(true),
    })
// => You cannot set the quantity for metered plans.
```

Normally I'd have to report usage using another API, but I can't do that with an upcoming invoice.

Comment: I do not think this is currently possible. I do see that you can clear the usage in the Upcoming Invoice API, https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming?lang=go#upcoming_invoice-subscription_items-clear_usage but not adding a usage. I think you’d need to create the Subscription first and then surface the total amount including the tax.

Comment: @pgs Thanks, but also, WTF Stripe. Most countries require you to show the final price including tax ahead of time.